# How to have bullet points in Gherkin files?

Tags: cucumber, gherkin

I need to make a list of instructions on how the code runs and I this needs to put this inside a scenario part of a feature inside a Gherkin file.

Bullet points would provide a succinct way of explaining what the algorithm does.

I have tried googling bullet points in Gherkin, but have had no success.

```
Feature: My feature
  Scenario:
  Instructions to run are as follows:
  # Bullet points needed here
  * Do this
  * Do that
  etc...
```

I expect to be able to write a bullet point list without having to use comments inside the BDD scenario section of the Gherkin file.

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded with this code :

Fonctionnalité: Get
  - Tests 
  - Test 2
    - Sub test